# Type inference in loop that uses var

Tags: java, java-10

Generally I know how works type inference in Java. But I'm curious how it works in loop when you use JDK 10 new feature  ***var***.

I mean that I can write loop in this way

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
//something to do
}
```

How does the compiler infer that there should be an *int* and not a *long*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `0` is an `int` literal. `0L` is a `long` literal.

`true` is a `boolean` literal, `"true"` is a `String` literal. The compiler has no problems handling simple cases like these.

Comment: Okay I understand but 0 is default value for byte and short too

Comment: @implssv there is no such thing as a `byte` or `short` literal. You would have to write `var i = (byte) 0` to use a `byte`. You can write `byte b = 0;` because `0` is a compile-time constant, and the compiler can determine that it fits in a byte. (This is called a [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).

Comment: Great. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: @AndyTurner Also, the fact that `0` is an `int` literal is covered by the §15.8.1 of the JLS.